# Programmatically align the webview to center of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-webview, center

I have a LinearLayout in the xml and now I am adding the webview to that LinearLayout but the webview is displaying on top its not aligning in the center.

this is how its displaying now.

```
webview content
--------------------
webview content
--------------------
webview content
--------------------
```

Code

```
        WebView answerHtml = new WebView(this);
        answerHtml.setId(i);
        answerHtml.setOnTouchListener(AnswerListener);
        answerHtml.setBackgroundColor(0);
        answerHtml.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_back);
        answerHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        answerHtml.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, a.getText(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        ansCellLayout.addView(answerHtml,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,80));
        ansCellLayout is a Linearlayout  defined in xml.
```

**SOLVED**

```
answerHtml.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<html><head><style type='text/css'>html,body {margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;}html {display: table;}body {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;}</style></head><body><p>"+a.getText()+"</p></body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Now its vertically centered to the layout.

Answer (score 1):

use this sample and customize it:

```
            String desiredContent = "my test html";
            String strBody = "<html>"
                + "<head>"
                + "     <style type=\"text/css\">"
                + "     @font-face "
                + "         {   font-family: Tahoma;"
                + "             src:url(\"~/android_asset/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf\") "
                + "         }"
                + "     #text"
                + "         {   font-family: Tahoma;"
                + "             font-size:14;"
                + "             text-align: center;"
                + "         }"
                + "     </style>"
                + ""
                + "</head>"
                + "<body dir=\"rtl\" id=\"text\">"
                + desiredContent 
                + " </body></html>  ";

        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strBody, "text/html", "utf-8",
                null);
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your LineraLayout like this:

**EDIT 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

From Activity :

```
        LinearLayout ansCellLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        WebView answerHtml = new WebView(this);
        answerHtml.setId(1);
       // answerHtml.setOnTouchListener(AnswerListener);
        answerHtml.setBackgroundColor(0);
        answerHtml.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        answerHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        answerHtml.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "test test", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        ansCellLayout.addView(answerHtml,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,80));
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Goofy see my edit I have posted full code which works well for me.

Comment: i wil try that just a mintue

Comment: @Goofy try with "EDIT 1" I have posted this also works for me.

Comment: @Goofy is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in you activity:

```
ansCellLayout.setGravity ( Gravity.CENTER );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (it's an edit of Pratik's post):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:centerHorizontal="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```